# Power on unused pairs of Cat6a Ethernet cable / home made voltage regulator?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, ethernet

At the end of the afternoon, I have been given the following task : try to get a sensor working over a 100 m Ethernet cable (Cat6a, i.e. 4 twisted pairs, each pair shielded individually). The challenging point is it has to be done by tomorrow evening, or not at all (so no time to order anything).

The sensor requires a 10 Mb/s ethernet connection (i.e. 2 twisted pairs) and DC voltage (14-32 V). The current is very variable (about 200 mA most of the time, with 1-1.5 A bursts every 100 ms (I haven't had time to characterize them exactly, educated guess would be about 10- ms long).

The cable is 7.5 Ω for one wire one way.

So far, I tried a quick connection (with screw terminals), using the 2 unused pairs for power (for each pair, I used 1 wire for +, one for -), supplying 31 V (from lab supply, 60 V max) to get enough margin and minimize current.

I managed to communicate with the sensor while in standby (i.e. no current bursts), but it becomes unstable as soon as I turn it on (interface sometimes complaining of unstable power, sometimes just crashing).

Is using one wire per pair for + and the other for - the good choice, or would it be better to use one pair for + and one pair for -?

I also tried so far is adding the biggest electrolytic capacitor I had (1500 µF) in parallel to the supply at the sensor side of the cable: it wasn't enough to stabilize voltage (I didn't had time to to precise measurements, but downwards voltage spikes of several volts persist. I can of course add a few more capacitors in parallel, but without much hope.

I sadly don't have any converter with adequate output voltage and enough current, nor a PoE receiver to generate the 24 V from PoE.

Maybe there is a way to generate a crude power regulator from components I have in stock (capacitors, resistors, N-MOS, diodes bipolar transistors (NPN for sure, PNP to be checked), AOPs, comparators, logic gates, relays, Arduinos, step down converters to convert down to 5 V or 3.3 V, linear regulators with 5V or 3.3V output; NB: I don't have inductors in stock, excepted random ones I could unsolder from some old PCBs)?

What I haven't tried yet (that might help, but I don't have much hope), is restrain the ethernet connection at 10 Mb/s from the laptop to be sure 100 Mb/s isn't used. But as there are complaints about power, I don't think it will solve the problem.

Do you have any idea what I could try to get it working (however dirty it is)?

EDIT:
As asked, the sensor is a [MT370s](https://www.blueprintsubsea.com/downloads/oculus/DA-148-P01443-05.pdf) (a sonar). I think I put all useful information from the datasheet directly into the question. but feel free to double check if you want.

EDIT2: problem solved:

- cable reduced to 70 m (instead of 110 initially)
- powered with 30 V
- I added 2 electrolytic capacitors of 1500 µF each across the supply line near the sensor: without one, the sensor worked but sometimes crashed (I added the second one just in case)

Comment: Do you have some LiPo cells to deliver the peak current locally?

Comment: @Sandro need to have more information, like sensor model#, edit the question and reopen

Comment: @Jens : I was thinking about it too, but I only have 1S cells, and not even enough from the same type (so I would need to put different types in series). Combined with the fact that the system will go under water (even if epoxy sealed) and will have to travel by plane, I think this option is too dangerous. But otherwise a good idea.

Comment: @VoltageSpike : I didn't added the model# (but all relevant information instead) in order to avoid useless conversations about the fact that all this system goes underwater (sealed in epoxy). But as you asked, I added it. Feel free to ask for any other information you feel useful

Comment: Don’t know where you are, but in most places you can certainly order a PoE injector and a splitter and get it delivered tomorrow (or even today).

Comment: Can you use two cables? One for power (4 pairs), one for data? Or maybe even 6 pairs (4 from one cable, 2 from the other) for power. At what voltage do you measure 1.5A? If 32V that's a lot of power to get through that cable.

Comment: @jcaron : PoE injectors, we do have, but we don't have a PoE splitter (and beeing in a small city, no, we can't get delivered same day (even next day delivery is not always reliable).

Comment: OK, problem solved : I reduced the cable to 70m, supplied it with 30V, and added 2 electrolytic capacitors (1500µF each) across the supply near the sensor. But I'm still curious if using one pair for + and one pair for - is better or worse than having one + and one - inside each of the 2 pairs used for power

Comment: Assuming your device needs 24 V, you have on average 0.2+(10/100)*(1.5-0.2) = 330 mA or 7.92 W which needs to be supplied. A 48 V PoE injector will happily do that for you. To hold up 1.5 A with say 2 V allowed drop for 10 ms, you need 7.5 mF of capacitance. I would try to have an intermediate rail which can allow much bigger deltaV to minimize the capacitor you need.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is solved and no answer was posted